# Referencing class library .dll file in Azure Function, do I need to setup the services in Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, reference, azure-functions

I've setup DI in my Azure Function by using `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. So this is my startup:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IThingFactory, ThingFactory>();
    }
}
```

This works fine within the project however I have added a reference to `SomeOtherProject.dll` (One of my *class library* projects).

My question is: do i need to setup services for each of the interfaces & implementations from `SomeOtherProject` that i'll be using?

Comment: yes, and if you are using the same DI configuration in multiple places, you could make a separate project named something like SomeOtherProject.DependencyInjection and put your Configure method there.

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on you.

If you want to use [Dependency Injection of Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection)(it's recommended), you should always setup services for each of the `interfaces & implementations` from `SomeOtherProject.dll`.

For example, in `SomeOtherProject.dll`, you have `an interface` named `IRepository` and `a class` named `Repository` which implements the interface. And then in the azure function, you reference this `SomeOtherProject.dll`, you want to use [Dependency injection like this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#use-injected-dependencies), you must register them in the `Startup class` like this `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>();`

But if you don't choose to use `Dependency Injection`, there is no need to do that, just use them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is no need. if you are using dll reference, after adding references,it should be free to use SomeOtherProject's interfaces and implementations.